# Which AC/DC album were they playing in "Voroshilovgrad"?

Tags: serhiy-zhadan, voroshilovgrad, ukrainian-language

Prior to playing a soccer game, the players demand some music, and someone obliges by playing some AC/DC from "circa 1981" whose "terrible guitar licks sent us back to a black pit" and sent them "closer to God and the devil."

The "black pit" part suggests the *Back in Black* album, but that was actually released in 1980. The "closer to... the devil" suggests *Highway to Hell*, but that was released in 1979. Their 8th studio album, *For Those About to Rock We Salute You*, was released in 1981.

Which album is the author referring to here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was probably the "Back in Black" album; while released in Europe in late July 1980, singles from it were released as late as December 1980 (possibly leading to the date confusion, especially since they also released an album in 1981).

The "closer to God, closer to the devil" line was actually probably referring to *Hell's Bells*, which includes the following lines:

> **I'll give you black sensations up and down your spine**
> If you're into evil, you're a friend of mine
> See the white light flashing as I split the night
> **'Cause if good's [sometimes transcribed as "God"] on the left, then I'm sticking to the right**

> I won't take no prisoners, won't spare no lives
> Nobody's putting up a fight
> I got my bell, I'm gonna take you to hell
> **I'm gonna get ya, Satan get ya**

Significantly, this is the first track of the *Back in Black* album.